# How come the Beast was able to save Belle from the wolves?

Tags: beauty-and-the-beast-2017

After the "Be Our Guest" number, Belle goes to the West Wing where she finds the enchanted rose. But the Beast appears and scares her away, angry that she might have caused another petal to fall. Yet, just a few minutes later, the Beast saves Belle, who had fled with her horse, from the wolves.

So he just told her angrily to go away, yet he followed her through the magically snowy forest just in time to save her. Why?

Comment: question title and body not matching

Answer (score 1):

He yelled because he was afraid. But he still cares about Belle at this point. He's being prideful and let's her go. But he's sitting on a high point of the castle which gives him the view of the entire forest and can see her the entire way. He was able to see her in danger and ran towards her.

Also the forest is magical so reality of distance isn't an issue.